# How to register a global protocol handler for electron app?

Tags: windows, electron, protocol-handler

I have an electron app built with electron-builder where I set a custom protocol handler

```
 protocols: [
          {
            name: 'My App',
            role: 'Viewer',
            schemes: ['my-app']
          }
        ],
```

The app is installed globally for all users. When I try to open the app through a link `my-app://something` it does not work. I have to manually open the electron app first, after that the link works. This is a problem because I can have multiple windows accounts and manually starting my app for each one so that the link works is not a solution. I also tried registering a global protocol handler in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\myapp` but it does not work. Any ideas?